# ScalaMock does not work with ScalaTest's TestNG/JUnit Support Traits

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'm trying to use ScalaMock with ScalaTest as such:

```
class MyTest extends TestNGSuite with MockFactory with ProxyMockFactory {

  @Test def someTest() = ...
}
```

However, I get the following compile error with this code:

```
ERROR: MyTest.scala: error: overriding method runTests in trait TestNGSuite of type 
       (testName: Option[String], reporter: org.scalatest.Reporter, stopper: org.scalatest.Stopper, 
       filter: org.scalatest.Filter, configMap: Map[String, Any], distributor: Option[org.scalattest.Distributor], 
       tracker: org.scalatest.Tracker)Unit;
INFO: method runTests in trait MockFactory of type (testName: Option[String], 
      reporter: org.scalatest.Reporter, stopper: org.scalatest.Stopper, filter: org.scalatest.Filter, 
      configMap: Map[String,Any], distributor: Option[org.scalatest.Distributor],
      tracker: org.scalatest.Tracker)Unit cannot overrride final member;
ERROR: other members with override errors are runTest
INFO: class MyTest extends TestNGSuite with MockFactory with ProxyMockFactory {
            ^
```

Looking at the source it looks like ScalaMock's MockFactory cannot be mixed into TestNGSuite or JUnitSuite.  ScalaMock's documentation is a bit sparse.

Is there any way to use ScalaMock with ScalaTest's Junit/TestNG support?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that ScalaMock with TestNG isn't something I've tested (TBH, I hadn't even noticed that ScalaTest had a TestNG runner!).

Can you please report this as an issue on the [ScalaMock tracker](https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/issues) and I'll see what I can do. If you can make a small example project that illustrates the problem available, that would be even better :-)